# Change "Edit Address" Template Layout with local.xml

Tags: layout, local.xml

I want to change the Edit Address Template Layout with **local.xml**.

- /customer/address/new/
- /customer/address/edit/

Here is my relevant part in **local.xml**:

```
<customer_address_edit translate="label">
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</customer_address_edit>
<customer_address_new translate="label">
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</customer_address_new>
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<customer_address_form>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </customer_address_form>
```

You can check the which handle the page is getting called by the following code

```
<?php echo "<pre>"; print_r(Mage::app()->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles()); exit; ?>
```

after this is done clear cache

Answer (score 1):

Raptor.amagento is used the handler `customer_address_form` for  route ->`customer/address/new`  and

`customer/address/edit`. So change it

```
   <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <layout version="0.1.0">
    <customer_address_form translate="label">
            <reference name="root">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
                </action>
             </reference>
    </customer_address_form>
     </layout>
```